# glEnd error (mesa-libGL/GLU) installing "rgl" package on Centos6.7

Tags: r, centos6, bioconductor, rgl, mesa

I try to install "rgl" on CentOS 6.7 but I cannot make it works.
Saw numerous similar issues but no solution worked for me.

My system:

> Centos 6.7
>   R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
>   Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

**NOTE** : The problem evolved, you can jump directly to the **UPDATE** part. I will reformat whole post when the problem will be solved.

The error (using bioconductor)

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rgl")
...
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rgl’
```

same issue using

```
install.packages("rgl", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

I tried solution here
[How to install R “rgl” package under centos 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512641/how-to-install-r-rgl-package-under-centos-6)

Here is my installed X11 library :

```
>yum list installed |grep X11  
libX11.x86_64                          1.6.0-6.el6                      @base   
libX11-common.noarch                   1.6.0-6.el6                      @base   
libX11-devel.x86_64                    1.6.0-6.el6                      @base
```

But it still fails.

I also installed devtools and imported library, it does not fixed the issue.

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
library(devtools)
biocLite("rgl")
... same issue
```

Spent hours on it, nothing worked

NB : I successfully installed it on my ubuntu, but there is no way to make it works on centos6.7 (the workstation)

**UPDATE**
Find that libpng-devel was missing (already had, libpng, libpng10, libpng10-devel)

```
sudo yum install libpng-devel.x86_64
```

The error changed
I then added more missing libraries

```
sudo yum install mesa-libGL
sudo yum install mesa-libGL-devel
sudo yum install mesa-libGLU
sudo yum install mesa-libGLU-devel
```

The error changed
I am still having problem

```
* installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -E
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
checking whether gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking whether  accepts -fvisibility... no
checking for libpng-config... yes
configure: using libpng-config
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking GL/gl.h usability... yes
checking GL/gl.h presence... yes
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking GL/glu.h usability... yes
checking GL/glu.h presence... yes
checking for GL/glu.h... yes
checking for glEnd in -lGL... no
configure: error: missing required library GL
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
```

Now if i locate libGL

```
locate libGL
/usr/lib/libGL.la
/usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.361.28
/usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM.so
/usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.361.28
/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
/usr/lib/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.361.28
/usr/lib/libGLX_indirect.so.0
/usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.361.28
/usr/lib/libGLdispatch.so.0
/usr/lib64/libGL.la
/usr/lib64/libGL.so
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGL.so.361.28
/usr/lib64/libGLESv1_CM.so
/usr/lib64/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.361.28
/usr/lib64/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib64/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib64/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
/usr/lib64/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.361.28
/usr/lib64/libGLU.so
/usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib64/libGLX_indirect.so.0
/usr/lib64/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib64/libGLX_nvidia.so.361.28
/usr/lib64/libGLdispatch.so.0
/usr/lib64/libGLw.so
/usr/lib64/libGLw.so.1
/usr/lib64/libGLw.so.1.0.0
/usr/share/doc/mesa-libGLw-6.5.1
/usr/share/doc/mesa-libGLw-6.5.1/README
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/changed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/010c511f597ab7af9a62cb69e3efa97a86d8aed8-mesa-libGLU-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/a38f4280f482ab6f663312b4971b2355c27dedc6-mesa-libGLw-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/changed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/aa6576ce41dd030b88b08c1a166b3a367f685972-mesa-libGL-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/adc9d6749b6c635c773e81565cd5d39b0ab3b851-mesa-libGL-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/dc1a62e08fc366e4a97e261f5dc94d04019e1e68-mesa-libGLU-devel-10.4.3-1.el6-x86_64/releasever
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/checksum_data
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/checksum_type
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/command_line
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/from_repo
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/from_repo_revision
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/from_repo_timestamp
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/installed_by
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/reason
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/m/edbad91b2990d0cab1c3e8a029bcd7129ce3a1e5-mesa-libGLw-devel-6.5.1-10.el6-x86_64/releasever
```

**UPDATE2:**
Following @MartinMorgan help I downloaded ligGL package and configured it manually

```
./configure
```

gave me

```
configure: error: Direct rendering requires libdrm >= 2.4.38
```

So I had to install libdrm-devel

```
sudo yum install libdrm-devel
```

Then once again, error update!

```
configure: error: DRI3 requires xcb >= 1.9.3
```

But centos has the 1.9.1 installed

I decided to do it manually

```
wget https://xcb.freedesktop.org/dist/libxcb-1.9.3.tar.gz
```

But when I hit configure, it tell me that it needs xcb-proto 1.9
Yum repository for centOS6 only provide 1.8

Once again I went manually

```
wget https://xcb.freedesktop.org/dist/xcb-proto-1.9.tar.gz
```

But when I make install of it and go back to libxcb-1.9.3 it does not detect that xcb-proto is installed.

Whereas if I install the 1.8 xcb-proto from repositor, it detect it and tell me it is out of date.

By looking when xcb-proto 1.8 is installed with

```
rpm -ql xcb-proto
```

Output is

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/__init__.pyo
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/error.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/error.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/error.pyo
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/expr.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/expr.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/expr.pyo
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/matcher.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/matcher.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/matcher.pyo
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/state.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/state.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/state.pyo
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/xtypes.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/xtypes.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xcbgen/xtypes.pyo
/usr/share/doc/xcb-proto-1.8
/usr/share/doc/xcb-proto-1.8/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/xcb-proto-1.8/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/xcb-proto-1.8/README
/usr/share/doc/xcb-proto-1.8/TODO
/usr/share/doc/xcb-proto-1.8/xml-xcb.txt
/usr/share/pkgconfig/xcb-proto.pc
/usr/share/xcb
/usr/share/xcb/bigreq.xml
/usr/share/xcb/composite.xml
/usr/share/xcb/damage.xml
/usr/share/xcb/dpms.xml
/usr/share/xcb/dri2.xml
/usr/share/xcb/ge.xml
/usr/share/xcb/glx.xml
/usr/share/xcb/randr.xml
/usr/share/xcb/record.xml
/usr/share/xcb/render.xml
/usr/share/xcb/res.xml
/usr/share/xcb/screensaver.xml
/usr/share/xcb/shape.xml
/usr/share/xcb/shm.xml
/usr/share/xcb/sync.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xc_misc.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xcb.xsd
/usr/share/xcb/xevie.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xf86dri.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xf86vidmode.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xfixes.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xinerama.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xinput.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xkb.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xprint.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xproto.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xselinux.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xtest.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xv.xml
/usr/share/xcb/xvmc.xml
```

Whereas xcb-proto use python 2.7
I do not understand well the difference between how the system finds packages installed by yum and how it finds them when they are installed from tarball.

Comment: Check [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820865/error-in-installing-rgl-package) The message may appear if xquartz is missing

Comment: I thought quartz was for macOS, I will have a look

Comment: it might help to provide a few more lines before `configure: error` to indicate what configure is doing to try and find X11.

Comment: You can look for libGL -- `locate libGL` -- if it's not installed, then it means finding the appropriate package. If it is installed then perhaps it is in a location that is unknown; see your operating system ldconfig and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Thank you for helping @MartinM, I updated thanks to you

Comment: @MartinMorgan Updated. If you have any idea I am in dead end.

Comment: You can download and untar the package tarball, `cd` into the package directory, and run ./configure. It will fail. There'll be a file conftest.c, the command to compile it and the error will be in config.log (toward the end). Also, ./configure --help provides options for installation.

Comment: make sure that xcb-proto-1.9 is installed in a standard location, or use ldconfig to add the installed location to the library search path.

Answer (score 1):

This is the packages that I use to get rgl on 6.7 (and 7.x)

```
yum install mesa-libGLU-devel libGL-devel libpng-devel libX11-devel
```